# Device driver in uboot

Tags: driver, u-boot

I am a newbie of u-boot and I have a question when I am developing u-boot that if I add/init a device driver into u-boot, how does the u-boot know where and what the corresponding device is? Is there a way to register a device or device tree like the kernel does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the new board to U-boot it goes like this. When you config the Uboot it will select the corresponding device that is mentioned at step 4.

Device tree(DTS) also used where you can list the device info that is introduced from 2012. This just describes about the hardware of your board.

---

1. The board file needs to be created `-> board/x_vendor/your_board/your_board.c`
2. Config file can be Kconfig         `-> board/x_vendor/x_board/Kconfig`
3. Makefile for the board `-> board/x_vendor/your_board/Makefile`
4. defconfig for the board
   When you do this it will add the corresponding device code.

   Example.

   ```
   configs/your_board_defconfig
   CONFIG_ARM=y
   CONFIG_ARCH_MX6=y
   CONFIG_TARGET_MY_BOARD=y
   CONFIG_MXC_UART=y
   ```
5. Header file for the board  `->include/configs/your_board.h`
6. board Kconfig needs to be sourced in architecture Kconfig. `-> arch/arm/Kconfig`